# Knot group of a field extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, knot-theory, terminology, class-field-theory

**Notation**: 
$L/K$, finite extension of global fields 
$K^\times$, unit group of $K$ 
$L^\times$, units group of $L$ 
$\mathbb{A}_L^\times$, ideles of $L$ 
$N_{L/K}$, the norm map

The **knot group** of an extension of global fields $L/K$ is defined as the quotient group of 'local norms' by 'global norms':
$$\mathfrak{K}(L/K):=\frac{K^\times \cap N_{L/K}(\mathbb{A}_L^\times)}{N_{L/K}(L^\times)}.$$

**Question**: In what way is this related to knots?

**Remarks**: 1. The terminology *knot group* appears to have been introduced by Arnold Scholz, in the papers *Totale Normenreste, die keine Normen sind, als Erzeuger nichtabelscher Körpererweiterungen*. Part I (1936), Part II (1940). (I have not looked into these papers yet.) 
2. I don't think this is related to the usual analogy between knots and number fields (but I could be wrong). For example, the usual knot group of a knot $\mathcal{K}$ in $S^3$ is the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^3\setminus \mathcal{K})$. The analog of this should be something like $\pi_1(\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)\setminus \mathfrak{p})$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of a global field $K$ and $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_K$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the analogy between number fields/primes and 3-manifolds/knots was developed much later than the references you mention. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_topology )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arnold Scholz was fond of a colorful language in mathematics. I don't think there's any connection to actual knots except perhaps for a faint reference to the Gordian knot, which is difficult to solve without a striking idea.

Comment: Thanks! Gordian knot would be a fitting reference, but perhaps calling it the *Gordian group* would have been less confusing.